# Append tables in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, union

If I have the two following tables,

Table1

```
ItemNo  Desc    Order Number    Qty      S_Date     Location
AA       AA         AAA          A     AA/AA/AAAA     AAAA
BB       BB         BBB          B     BB/BB/BBBB     BBBB
CC       CC         CCC          C     CC/CC/CCCC     CCCC
```

Table 2

```
M_Order Item    M_Date      Total
XXX      X      XX/XX/XXXX   XX
YYY      Y      YY/YY/YYYY   YY
```

Can anyone advice me how to get the following table please.

Result Table

```
ItemNo  Desc    Order Number    Qty     S_Date    Location   M_Date     Total
AA       AA        AAA           A    AA/AA/AAAA    AAAA        
BB       BB        BBB           B    BB/BB/BBBB    BBBB        
CC       CC        CCC           C    CC/CC/CCCC    CCCC        
X       XXX                                                 XX/XX/XXXX    XX
Y       YYY                                                 YY/YY/YYYY    YY
```

Thanks

Comment: why can't you use outer joins

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a `full outer join` trick:

```
select t1.*, t2.*
from table1 t1 full outer join
     table2 t2
     on 1 = 0;
```

This will give you the columns in both tables.  Each row will be populated with values from only one of the tables.

Comment: the `1=0` is a nasty hack

Comment: @Giosco . . . It is perfectly valid SQL and appears to do exactly what the OP is asking for.  It is not a "hack" at all.

Comment: You are writing "trick" yourself ...Come on! You know pretty much that this can't be a serious solution.

Comment: I mean: OK, it works, but that's like using "goto" in c#

Comment: @SQLPolice . . . It is a "trick" in the sense that one wouldn't normally think of using `full outer join` for this purpose.  My reaction is more to the downvote than the description as a `hack`.  But, it is perfectly reasonably SQL, it does exactly what the OP wants, and it is ANSI standard as well.  Hard to see why anyone would downvote such an answer.

Comment: A `goto` statement is also "correct" C#, but still it is considered to be "nasty". And your statement 1=0 is also of that category. It is not **intuitive**!!!. The common pattern for such a result set is `t1 full join t2 where t1.key is null or t2.key is null`

Comment: @SQLPolice . . . I find `1 = 0` much more intuitive than your version.  The `1 = 0` for "false" and `1 = 1` for "true" have been used in SQL for as long as I can remember -- and I have a very long memory in this area.  I have never seen what you call "the common pattern".

Comment: Join Diagram: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins

Answer (score 0):

Use the below query join those two tables.

I think you wish to combine the values of  two [(**ItemNo and Item**) and (**Desc and M_Desc**)] columns in same column and all the other columns separately.

```
SELECT CAST(ItemNo AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS ItemNo, CAST(Desc AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS Desc, OrderNumber, Qty, 
       S_Date, Location, NULL AS M_Date, NULL AS Total 
FROM Table1
UNION ALL
SELECT CAST(Item AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS ItemNo, CAST(M_Order AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS Desc, NULL AS OrderNumber, NULL AS Qty, 
       NULL AS S_Date, NULL AS Location, M_Date, Total 
FROM Table2
```

Comment: Gives an error 
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'XXXXX'  to data type smallint

Comment: You didn't mention the datatype of the columns. That the problem. I updated the query with Cast(). Plz check it now.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Gordons answer but the use of stars in SQL is one of the biggest NO NO's there is.
Also for the actual join part itself you need to do tablename.column = tablename.column on the unique columns. 1 = 0 is a bit ambiguous. but you get the picture

Comment: There is nothing ambiguous at all about "1 = 0".  It is always false.